# Does a find() operation on a MongoDB capped collection with an index maintain insertion order?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In a MongoDB database, I have a capped collection, where one of the fields of the documents in the collection is a boolean. Let's suppose the boolean field is called `isRelevant`.
In addition, there is a single partial index on `isRelevant`, for documents where `isRelevant: false` (beyond the default index on `_id`).

I understand from the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/capped-collections/#query-a-capped-collection) for capped collections that in general the documents returned by a find query are guaranteed to be returned in their original insertion order, but I'm not sure this still holds when using the mentioned partial index.

My question is, if I perform a find operation on the collection with a limit of e.g. 500 and filter of `{isRelevant:false}` to retrieve from the collection the first 500 documents where `isRelevant:false`, are the documents returned guaranteed to be in their original insertion order? If so, how can this be understood from the MongoDB documentation?